# What type of strategy game is this? You rearrange positions?

Tags: terminology, sliding-puzzle

What do you call games where you have to move and re-arrange cars or boxes to move a goal box into a location.  There have been games like this since Atari, as far as I know.  It's some kind of tactical game.  I can maybe draw an example, as a kind of flow chart:

1.

```
Goal Block Item
xxxx       xxxx
```

2.

```
Goal       Item
xxxx Block xxxx
```

3.

```
Goal Item  <--
xxxx Block xxxx
```

4.

```
WIN  <---------
xxxx Block xxxx
```

If you possibly know the first game of this kind, I would be interested in that, or any game names.  If you add pictures or media or links to the same, that would be useful.

Comment: Sounds like "Traffic" or "Rush Hour"

Comment: You may also have a look at Jaap Scherphuis' beautiful puzzle page. There is a graphical overview and some of the pages contain Java applets you can run in your browser :) http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/indxgraf.htm

Comment: Some of the [Hoshi Saga](http://nekogames.jp/mt/2007/05/post_16.html) mini-games are also clever, original and beautiful sliding blocks puzzles.  Do not hesitate to give it a try !

Comment: @Anto it's noisy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd say puzzle game, and more accurately [sliding blocks puzzle game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle).

> **Examples of sliding puzzles**
>
> - Fifteen puzzle
> - Inakube
> - **Klotski** (mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47680/15726) by Hex)
> - Minus Cube
> - Jumbly
> - **Sokoban** (mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47681/15726) by Konrad)

Otherwise, there's also [a list of puzzle game types on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_puzzle_video_games), but I think that the previously given term is the best match.

Comment: Aaaannnnnd I've just discovered there was even [an already existing tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle) for that kind of game xD

Comment: Would a sort-of similar sort of piece-rearranging game, like [the magnet puzzle](http://themagnetpuzzle.com/) be considered a sliding puzzle game?

Comment: Looks like, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like [Sokoban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) (or its clones) to me.

Comment: That wikipedia page says that is a "transport puzzle". I think that is a fitting name.

Comment: Sokoban was exactly the kind of game I was looking for, Konrad.  Do you know if this was the first game of its kind, and if there's an analog analogue?

Comment: Now I'm really conflicted.  I think this answer may be more accurate than the top answer.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, then this is what should be accepted. Votes come from community, "tick" from original poster. :-)

Comment: There's doesn't seem to be a precise name for this kind of games, Wikipedia calls them "Sokoban-type puzzles". If you google for sokoban, there's a ton of clones available for free.

Answer (score 8):

I know a nice flash version of this called [Gridlock](http://www.corwin.ca/gridlock/). There was a Windows version of this game quite a few years back called [Klotski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klotski).

These games generally seem to fall into the ["sliding block puzzle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_block_puzzle) category.

Comment: Do you know the genre?  I'm going to leave the question open for a day or two in hopes someone will post it.

Comment: Aw, man.  I want to say this is the best answer because Gridlock was such a great recommendation, but the community had so much love for the "Sliding Puzzle" reference that I had to put my own opinion aside.  Thanks for the speed, though, man.